# JAWS execution issue

Tags: java, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I am using [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) (Java API for WordNet Searching) and have set up the wordnet dictionary with VM Arguments in eclipse. I downloaded the jaws-bin.jar file and placed it in my project directory C:\Users\My-pc\Projects\MyApp\src. After this, I am trying to set up the classpath using the method provided in the link:

```
java -classpath .;C:\Users\My-pc\Projects\MyApp\src\jaws-bin.jar -Dwordnet.database.dir=C:\WordNet-3.0\dict MyAppName
```

But I am getting this error: "Could not find or load main class MyAppName". As a result I can't import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.* and continue my work. Can anyone help me out in resolving this problem. Thanks.

P.S The class MyAppName contains this function:

```
public static void main() throws IOException{
...}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the method in class "MyAppName". I have named the class "MyAppName" for trying the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it. Was browsing in src folder of code instead of bin folder where .class files are placed.

```
java -classpath .;C:\Users\My-pc\Projects\MyApp\bin\jaws-bin.jar -Dwordnet.database.dir=C:\WordNet-3.0\dict MyAppName
```

Though, the import issue was resolved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23643466/2852045).