# JAWS import issue

Tags: java, import, wordnet, jaws-wordnet

I am using [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) (Java API for WordNet Searching) and have set up the wordnet dictionary with VM Arguments in eclipse. I downloaded the jaws-bin.jar file and placed it in my project directory C:\Users\My-pc\Projects\MyApp\src. After this, I ran the code successfully using:

```
java -classpath .;C:\Users\My-pc\Projects\MyApp\bin\jaws-bin.jar -Dwordnet.database.dir=C:\WordNet-3.0\dict MyAppName
```

Now when I import the package "edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.*", it is giving the error "The import edu cannot be resolved". I followed the set-up guide closely but can't figure out what is wrong. Can anyone please help me in resolving this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it right by downloading the source files from [here](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/jaws-src.zip) and placing it in my project.